# Arabic spannable string doesn't show when made clicakble

Tags: android, android-layout, arabic, spannablestring

I'm using a spannableStringBuilder to show a text with arabic words in it. I'm using following piece of code

```
tvTags.setText(postViewModel.getBoxesSpannableString());
tvTags.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance();
```

When i comment the 'setMovementMethod' method then it shows the text but ofcourse it is not clickable, but when i uncomment this line then it is clickable but text doesn't show. But it takes its proper space in the view like empty spaces. It happens with Arabic text not with english. What could be the problem?

Comment: Just try putting `setMovementMethod ` before the `setText`

Comment: tried that as well, but issue was not that. I found that singleLine=true and setMovementMethod together cause this issue.